# Python import fails with message: ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Tags: python, import, module, null

I use an M1 MacBook Pro. My Python programs started to fail when they had worked before. The programs would fail with the error message in the title of this post and in each case it was due to an import statement in the program. Others have asked similar questions, but none of the answers solved my problem. Different solutions fixed their individual problems. None of the solutions fixed my problem.

I checked my modules for null characters and there were none. Someone said the problem was the Python interpreter. I reloaded it and that did not fix the problem.

I can't imagine what is causing this new problem. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you please answer your own question so other users find the answer a bit more easy? Also, [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72792665/edit) and make it clear what exactly the question is and move the "answer" to the answer you'll write.

Comment: Thanks, for your guidance, lepsch. I would have just posted an answer to the existing question, but it was so popular, that I wasn't allowed to post an answer with out 10 points. I'm new and I don't have 10 points.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be due to some aliases I made of the module files in order to have easier access to them. I had removed the word alias from the file names, making them the same as the name of the module files that I keep in the .local folder.

I put the alias files in a folder where I keep my programs. Evidently, when running a program from that folder, Python was trying to load the modules from the aliases it found in the same folder. The alias files have null characters in them. Some programs wouldn't run in Visual Studio Code IDE as well. Evidently Python searched in the folder with the aliases before searching in the .local/.../site-packages folder. I put the word alias back in the name of my alias files. That fixed the problem.